Clarification of the Kapitza-Dirac Effect
I'm currently learning about the Kapitza-Dirac effect and wanted to confirm whether I have a correct understanding of it. It is difficult to find diagrams that provide a clear step-by-step explanation. Is my below understanding correct?
Let an electron be traveling on the x-axis and the two counter-propagating light waves be traveling in the +y and -y direction. First, the free electron absorbs the photon traveling in the +y direction, now gaining momentum $\hbar k$ in the +y direction.
Then, the photon traveling in the -y direction hits the electron and stimulates emission. The photon that is emitted by stimulation travels in the -y direction, and the photon that caused the stimulated emission also continues traveling in the -y direction, both with momentum $\hbar k$. To maintain the conservation of momentum, the electron now has momentum $2 \hbar k$ in the +y direction.
Is this correct? Am I thinking of this incorrectly?

Correct, that's an intuitive way to understand the Kapitza-Dirac effect. However, free electron-photon absorption violates energy-momentum conservation, so it relies on energy-time uncertainty to occur briefly.
